# Agrupar por columna y fila

Tags: r

Tengo el siguiente df:

```
   df <- read.table(text="col1 col2 col3
    1  pepe      12
    2 juan         2
    3 rojo        33
    4 rojo        44
    5 azul        45
    6 azul         5
    7 amarillo   100
    8 amarillo   200
    9 amarillo   150
    10 rojo      200
    11 azul       25
    12 amarillo   23
    13 azul       50", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

y me gustaría agruparlo por la columna id, pero solo algunos casos, por ejemplo los ids
3,4, y 10 por un lado, y por otro lado los 7,8,9,12. De forma que quedaría

```
col1         col2        col3
1            pepe         12
2            juan          2
3,4,10       rojo        277
5            azul         45
6            azul          5
7,8,9,12     amarillo    473
11           azul         25
13           azul         50
```

No sé si se puede agrupar por columna indicando las filas.

Comment: En tu ejemplo, el grupo correspondiente a los id 3,4,10 tiene dos colores, rojo y azul, pero a la hora de agrupara sería un solo grupo dónde el color sería rojo ¿esto es un problema del ejemplo o ese sería el criterio?

Comment: podría ser así el criterio, agrupar aún cuando los colores son distintos, pero creo que de momento en mis datos reales no se da, por lo que cambio el color para que el ejemplo se entienda mejor.  Id 3,4,10 de un mismo color, 7,8,9,12 de un mismo color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es utilizar la librería `dplyr`, pero para obtener el mismo resultado que deseas, hay que agrupar los valores de la col1 en base a las condiciones que describes, y colocar este resultado en una nueva columna. Y luego con la función `group_by` puedes agrupar los valores de la col3 en una nueva col3 actualizada y eliminando la anterior.

```
data_frame %>% 
  mutate(
    grupo = ifelse(col1 %in% c(3,4,10), "grupo_1: (3,4,10)", 
            ifelse(col1 %in% c(7,8,9,12), "grupo_2: (7,8,9,12)", col1)
  )) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  mutate(
    col3_new = sum(col3)
  ) %>% 
  select(-col3) %>% 
  distinct(col3_new, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
   col1 col2     grupo               col3_new
  <int> <chr>    <chr>                  <int>
1     1 pepe     1                         12
2     2 juan     2                          2
3     3 rojo     grupo_1: (3,4,10)        277
4     5 azul     5                         45
5     6 azul     6                          5
6     7 amarillo grupo_2: (7,8,9,12)      473
7    11 azul     11                        25
8    13 azul     13                        50
```

Con un poco más de código, el resultado queda en la misma tabla que describes:

```
data_frame %>% 
  mutate(
    grupo = ifelse(col1 %in% c(3,4,10), "(3,4,10)", 
            ifelse(col1 %in% c(7,8,9,12), "(7,8,9,12)", col1)
  )) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  mutate(
    col3_new = sum(col3)
  ) %>% 
  select(-col3) %>% 
  distinct(col3_new, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(
    col3 = col3_new
  ) %>% 
  select(col1 = grupo, col2, col3, -col1, -col3_new)

 col1       col2      col3
  <chr>      <chr>    <int>
1 1          pepe        12
2 2          juan         2
3 (3,4,10)   rojo       277
4 5          azul        45
5 6          azul         5
6 (7,8,9,12) amarillo   473
7 11         azul        25
8 13         azul        50
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes hacer es generar una nueva columna en función de los criterios que manejas, un forma podría ser indicando los `id` en particular que deberían "juntarse":

```
df %>% 
  mutate(grupo=case_when(
    col1 %in% c(3, 4, 10) ~ '3,4,10',
    col1 %in% c(7, 8, 9, 12) ~ '7,8,9,12',
    TRUE ~ as.character(col1)
  )) %>% 
  group_by(grupo, col2) %>% 
  summarise(col3=sum(col3))
```

La otra sería usando el "color" como grupo alternativo de agrupamiento, solo en el caso de ciertos colores:

```
df %>% 
  mutate(grupo=case_when(
    col2 %in% c('amarillo', 'rojo') ~ col2,
    TRUE ~ as.character(col1)
  )) %>% 
  group_by(grupo) %>% 
  summarise(col3=sum(col3))
```

Comment: Gracias!! Aunque de esta forma la columna col2 donde vienen los nombres y colores se pierde.

Comment: Solo habría que agregarla a la agrupación