# Automatizar agrupaciones

Tags: r

Tengo dos df:

**DF1:**

```
df1 <- read.table(text="col1 col2 col3
     1  pepe      12
     2 juan         2
     3 rojo        33
     4 rojo        44
     5 azul        45
     6 azul         5
     7 amarillo   100
     8 amarillo   200
     9 amarillo   150
     10 rojo      200
     11 azul       25
     12 amarillo   23
     13 azul       50",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

**DF2:**

```
df2 <- read.table(text="
col1         col2        col3
1            pepe         12
2            juan          2
3,4,10       rojo        277
5            azul         45
6            azul          5
7,8,9,12     amarillo    473
11           azul         25
13           azul         50",
header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Quiero ver si los dos df tienen la misma información. Para ello agrupo algunas filas del df1 usando [esta solución](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/561483/agrupar-por-columna-y-fila)

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(col1=case_when(
    col1 %in% c(3, 4, 10) ~ '3,4,10',
    col1 %in% c(7, 8, 9, 12) ~ '7,8,9,12',
    TRUE ~ as.character(col1)
  )) %>% 
  group_by(col1, col2) %>% 
  summarise(col3=sum(col3)) -> df11
```

Por lo que mi df11 ahora es:

```
col1     col2      col3
 1        pepe        12
 11       azul        25
 13       azul        50
 2        juan         2
 3,4,10   rojo       277
 5        azul        45
 6        azul         5
 7,8,9,12 amarillo   473
```

Para comparar los df los ordeno por la misma columna

```
df11[order(df11$col1),] -> df11
df2[order(df2$col1),] -> df2
```

y los comparo

```
compare(df11,df2)[2]


$detailedResult
col1 col2 col3 
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

El problema viene que esta parte hay que meterla a mano

```
  mutate(col1=case_when(
col1 %in% c(3, 4, 10) ~ '3,4,10',
col1 %in% c(7, 8, 9, 12) ~ '7,8,9,12'
```

Y los df a comparar van cambiando. A veces las agrupaciones son muchas, por lo que
meterlo a mano es engorroso.

Me gustaría que las agrupaciones las detectara de forma automática.

```
    df1$col1 <- as.character(df1$col1)
    anti_join(df2, df1, by="col1")

      col1     col2 col3
1   3,4,10     rojo  277
2 7,8,9,12 amarillo  473
```

Entonces sé que las agrupacione son (3,4,10) y (7,8,9,12)
pero no sé como meterlo en esta parte de forma automática

```
 mutate(col1=case_when(
    col1 %in% c(3, 4, 10) ~ '3,4,10',
    col1 %in% c(7, 8, 9, 12) ~ '7,8,9,12'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es construir los grupos a partir del `df2`, por ejemplo:

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 %>% 
  mutate(grupo=col1) %>% 
  separate_rows(col1, convert=TRUE) %>% 
  select(col1, grupo)

# A tibble: 13 x 2
    col1 grupo   
   <int> <chr>   
 1     1 1       
 2     2 2       
 3     3 3,4,10  
 4     4 3,4,10  
 5    10 3,4,10  
 6     5 5       
 7     6 6       
 8     7 7,8,9,12
 9     8 7,8,9,12
10     9 7,8,9,12
11    12 7,8,9,12
12    11 11      
13    13 13
```

Expandiendo los valores de `col1` de forma individual y conservando el grupo, ahora es mucho más simple, podemos unir `df1` y `df2` mediante un `left_join` y con los grupos ya definidos podemos agrupar:

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2 %>% 
              mutate(grupo=col1) %>% 
              separate_rows(col1, convert=TRUE) %>% 
              select(col1, grupo),
            by = "col1") %>% 
  mutate(grupo=ifelse(is.na(grupo), col1, grupo)) %>% 
  group_by(grupo, col2) %>% 
  summarise(col3=sum(col3), .groups="drop")

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  grupo    col2      col3
  <chr>    <chr>    <int>
1 1        pepe        12
2 11       azul        25
3 13       azul        50
4 2        juan         2
5 3,4,10   rojo       277
6 5        azul        45
7 6        azul         5
8 7,8,9,12 amarillo   473
```

Nota: `mutate(grupo=ifelse(is.na(grupo), col1, grupo))` es para el eventual caso en que tuvieras valores de `col1` en el `df1` pero no en el `df2`

Comment: Fantástico, como siempre. He visto que tienes un blog con paypal. Me haré una cuenta y donaré algo este finde.

Comment: Hola @DudaR, realmente no es necesario, disfruto responder preguntas, y que además la respuesta se útil, me resulta suficiente recompensa.  Saludos.

Comment: Lo envié ayer. Espero que haya llegado. Un saludo.

Comment: Si, muchísimas gracias colega, pero nuevamente, no era necesario. Saludos.